# How can I make show/hide div when radiobutton is checked or not, not only when I click it, but also when I call the data (check mark) from database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("id")=="pindah1"){
        $(".boxl").not(".pindah1").hide();
        $(".pindah1").show();
    }
    if($(this).attr("id")=="pindah2"){
        $(".boxl").not(".pindah2").hide();
        $(".pindah2").show();
    }

});
});
```

and this is my div which I want to show and hide whenever there's check mark on my radio button:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label>Apakah Sudah Pernah Pindah Pekerjaan?</label><br>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="pernahpindah" id = "pindah1" <?php if ($pernahpindah == 'Sudah Pernah') echo 'checked="checked"';?> value="pindah1"> Sudah Pernah<br />
                 </label>
              </div>
              <div class="radio">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="pernahpindah" id = "pindah2"<?php if ($pernahpindah == 'Belum Pernah') echo 'checked="checked"';?> value="pindah2"> Belum Pernah <br /><br/>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pindah1 boxl">
                <label>Nama Perusahaan Pertama</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="perusahaanpertama" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['perusahaanpertama']; ?>"/><br />
            </div>
            </div>
```

which is work very well.

The problem is when I save the data into database and when I want to edit again based on the data that stored in database before, the check mark remain on my radio button but the div didn't show, so I have to click on it again to make it appear

Comment: Add selected to the relevant field in php when you create the HTML

Comment: Check and uncheck your checkbox when page loads by using jquery [document ready](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) based on data that is coming and [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the check or uncheck event that will automatically show and hide your div.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use jQuery for that.  You already have the value from the database server side, so just set the style of the div by checking the variable in PHP that you have got out of the DB. (or set a CSS class with display:none on it and just add that class to the div).

As per http://api.jquery.com/hide/ using .hide and .show in jQuery are the equivalent of CSS display:none and display:block respectively.

```
<? 
$showDiv = 0; // lets assume I got 0 out of the db and stored in this variable ?>
<div class="form-group">
        <label>Apakah Sudah Pernah Pindah Pekerjaan?</label><br>
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="pernahpindah" id = "pindah1" <?= ($pernahpindah === 'Sudah Pernah' ? 'checked="checked"' :''); ?> value="pindah1"> Sudah Pernah<br />
             </label>
          </div>
          <div class="radio">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" name="pernahpindah" id = "pindah2"<?= ($pernahpindah === 'Belum Pernah' ? 'checked="checked"' :'');?> value="pindah2"> Belum Pernah <br /><br/>
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pindah1 boxl"<?= ($showDiv ? " style='display:none'":""); ?>> <? // Set the display on the DIV here based on the database value ?>
            <label>Nama Perusahaan Pertama</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="perusahaanpertama" type="text" value="<?php echo $row['perusahaanpertama']; ?>"/><br />
        </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: so, i've deleted my jquery script and put variable $showdiv and adding display none style. but my page still give me message that variable shwDiv undefined.